# Exclude un-used .class files

Tags: codenameone

I have a small app that im making. It uses the external bouncy castle crypto API as i need to use the SHA1 hashing function it provides as the codename one API excludes the native java one.

Problem is i only use the SHA1digest class.

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA1Digest;
```

but after i build the API the codename one build system puts the whole API in the final .jar file. which is 1.8mb. Now i cant build or test the app as its over the 1mb limit.

is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

We remove the redundant stuff in the final build but not at that stage.
If you want to reduce the bouncy castle library size I suggest you don't use the cn1lib and instead copy the sources you need into your project: https://github.com/codenameone/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/

You can do that selectively and as the project fails to compile you can add the additional dependencies. I'm sure it will still be smaller than the current cn1lib.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a self-contained class, without any import, with only a public static method the implements the SHA-256 hashing of a String (all other methods are private).

This class is fully compatible with Codename One, I tested it in Simulator, Android native, iOS native and Javascript.

The full code, with an example of usage, is here:
https://github.com/jsfan3/SHA-Codename-One

I compared the outputs of this class with http://www.convertstring.com/en/Hash/SHA256: they are the same.

Inside the Javadoc @author, I gave credits to Johan Stenberg: I took him code and I only slightly modified it to adapt it to the Codename One API.

The size of the Java class is about 8 kbyte, this could solve your issue, if you remove the bouncy castle cn1lib and if you need only this class.